# Getting part of referring url with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to set a cookie with a value that is made up of part of a referring url. The referring url looks something like:

```
http://webct.university.ac.uk/webct/urw/lc715920578061.tp721521425061/courseMenu.dowebct?
```

and I need to extract:

```
lc715920578061.tp721521425061
```

for reuse in another function.
Would this be regex? Could anyone help with the syntax?

Many thanks
Matthew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a regex and [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) like this:

```
var desired_part = document.referrer.replace(/^https?:\/\//gi, '').split('/')[3];
```

Comment: Why doesn't `document.referrer` work? (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_referrer.asp)

Comment: `substring(7)` won't work correctly if https is being used - it might be better to use a regex to remove the protocol.

Comment: Thanks, Jacob. Brilliant! What's the (7) refer to?

Comment: @Matthew It was originally supposed to strip out the leading `http://`, but now I changed it to a regexp so it will strip out `https://` as well. :)

Comment: @Matthew Don't forget to mark this as the accepted answer by clicking on the hollow checkmark to the left. Thanks! :)